# GitLab not connecting to EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, gitlab

I'm trying to create a Ci/CD pipeline on my Windows using GitLab and AWS. In order to connect it I used this command in PowerShell:

```
docker run --detach `
  --hostname 54.227.19.152 `
  --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 `
  --name gitlab `--restart always `
  --volume C:\srv\gitlab\config:/etc/gitlab `
  --volume C:\srv\gitlab\logs:/var/log/gitlab `
  --volume C:\srv\gitlab\data:/var/opt/gitlab `
gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

This worked as expected and after a few minutes the docker was running (healthily)

When I try to access GitLab by using the ip adress of the Ec2 instance it doesn't work.
What could be the issue?

I tried from gitbash, by shh-ing into the instance, aswell instead of powershell and thus using Linux which didn't work either and resulted in both docker and gitbash crashing.

Comment: What are the security group rules assigned to the EC2 instance?

Comment: There are none except for the default one which is. IPv4 SSH TCP 22 0.0.0.0/0